# How to send firebase push notification with overlapping topic

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The way I see it, this should be a common use case. For example I have 3 users who subscribe to following topic(s)

1. User A > "CNN"
2. User B > "Sports"
3. User C > "CNN", "Sports"

The current problem is when I tried to send notification with message "Man Utd won 5-0" for both topics "CNN" and "Sports", the 3rd user (User C) will actually get 2 same notification.

What kind of logic should I put in the backend to ensure the 3rd user will get only 1 notification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be done with an `OR` condition like this:

```
"('CNN' in topics || 'Sports' in topics)"
```

This message will be deliver to any user that is subscribed to `CNN`, to `Sports`, or to both.

For a more complete example and explanation see the Firebase documentation on [sending messages to topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics).

Comment: Interesting! Didnt know they have such thing as condition. Will read on it further.Thanks.